# changing the binary value of a columnin r based on flipping a coin

Tags: r

I have a column in my data frame (say : class). This is a binary class (will be 0/1).

I am trying to add some noise in this variable..

I am flipping a biased coin Whose probability of landing heads is say `0.2`. Every time I see a head, I flip the value in the cell. So, if the value was 0, now its 1 and vice versa

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# an example vector
set.seed(1)
vec <- sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0

# create 10 realizations of U(0,1)
coin <- runif(length(vec))
# [1] 0.2059746 0.1765568 0.6870228 0.3841037 0.7698414 0.4976992 0.7176185 0.9919061 0.3800352 0.7774452

# replace values in vec with their opposite (!vec) if coin <= 0.2
as.integer(xor(coin <= 0.2, vec))
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: @Sven When i do !vec, it returns NA?

Comment: @Fraz Maybe your `vec` is a factor. Try converting it into a numeric vector with `as.numeric(as.character(vec))`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: Yay ! :)

Comment: You could use `as.numeric(xor(coin < 0.2, vec))` instead of `ifelse`

Comment: The `xor` method gives the same output and is considerably faster

Comment: @Dason `xor` is great for this task. I modified the code accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation based on @Sven's solution would be

```
> (coin <- rbinom(length(vec), 1, 0.2))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
> vec
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
> ifelse(coin, !vec, vec)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

This simulates the coin toss directly using a Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A late addition, simple algorithm for a binary flip and vice versa:
y = -1*(x-1)

> vec <- sample(0:1, 10, TRUE) 
> vec 
> [1] 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
> (vec-1)*-1
> [1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1